# AWS Connect with lex and lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have built a simple telephone chatbot using Amazon Lex.  In a few of my intents I call on a lambda function to give a specific response based on the slot value.

However when I try this in Amazon Connect, the lambda function does not seem to get called!  Is there something I need to do to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you building this using console? Then you should get a promp asking for permissions for the intent to call the lambda, that needs to be approved so it can be called.

Also, there are two options in the console to call the Lambda, as initiation or fulfillment. Initiation happens while the intent is trying to get data from the user, and fulfillment gets called when all the slots are fulfilled.

If you are using the API, then it gets a bit trickier:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-cli-update-lambda.html

Comment: No, not using the console yet, but if that is easier by all means.Can you share instructions for the console?